# ASP.NET Migration - Path 'GET' is forbidden

Tags: asp.net

We have an ASP.NET application migrated from 2.0 to 4.0.

After the migration, while accessing root URL, it is throwing an exception "Path 'GET' is forbidden.". The default page is different than the pages in IIS default pages list ("Pages/DashBoard.aspx"). It is working while accessing full URL ("<>/Pages/DashBoard.aspx").

Any idea?

Application pool managed pipeline mode is "Classic".